# Should the WebContent Folder be added to BuildPath in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I'm building a Java Dynamic Web Application using JSP and Servlets. I noticed that the build path only contains the src folder.

I know that the build path is used to resolve dependencies. And the reason that made me look it up is that my JSP pages weren't getting checked for Java errors, only Html and CSS errors.

Could that be the reason? and if I add the WebContent folder to the build path create a security problem?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Validation most often happens when building, so are you letting Eclipse build your project? Check your Validation Preference pages and its project Property page, are the twp JSP  validators enabled? What happens when you right-click on your JSP and manually Validate?

Comment: It worked when I enabled project-specific settings. JSP Syntax validator was disabled by default apparently. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going to project Proprietes > Validation > Tick Enable project specific settings > and Tick Manual and Build JSP Content Validator in the list.